# Object slicing while casting in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

How casting statically while down casting, leads to object slicing? Like in the case below;

```
class Parent{ // base class
public:
    virtual void draw();
};

class Child: public Parent{ //derived class
public:
    void draw()
    {
       static_cast<Parent>(*this).draw();
       // do other stuff
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you looking for `dynamic_cast<Parent*>(this)->draw()`?  In this case you might want to apply the [non-virtual interface idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface) (also Item 34 in Effective C++).

Comment: Doing an implicit upcast (Parent::draw() ) solved the issue.

Comment: It's not an implicit up-cast, it's not any sort of cast. You just call it by a fully qualified name.

Comment: Requiring a derived-class method implementation to call the base-class implementation is bad OOP design (in any programming language). The non-virtual interface idiom is a superior solution for the sheer reason that the compiler can catch a missing function override but not a missing function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your'e not down-casting, your'e up-casting (sort of).

And it causes slicing because `static_cast<Parent>(*this)` creates a new temporary `Parent` object by copying `*this`. It's essentially equivalent to the following:

```
Parent{*this}.draw();
```

As per the C++ standard:

[[expr.static.cast/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#1)

> The result of the expression static_­cast(v) is the result of converting the expression v to type T. If T is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type, the result is an lvalue; if T is an rvalue reference to object type, the result is an xvalue; **otherwise, the result is a prvalue**. The static_­cast operator shall not cast away constness.

[[basic.lval/1.2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#1.2)

> ...
>
> - A prvalue is an expression whose evaluation **initializes an object** or a bit-field, or computes the value of the operand of an operator, as specified by the context in which it appears.
>
> ...